# NullPointerException on image verification in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Server with Java and trying to verify that an image is actually displayed. 
I am using the following code, but getting `NullPointerException`:

```
String imageURL = driver.findElement(By.xpath(imageXpath)).getAttribute("src");
assertTrue((Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", imageURL));
```

When I manually verify the URL stored in the variable `imageURL` I am getting a valid image, therefore I don't understand why am I getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Please provide exception log

Answer (score 1):

Might be `executeScript()` is returning `null`, that's why you are getting `NullPointerException`, This is possible due to timing problem, Your provided `javascript` would be return null instead of expected value, In this case you should try using `executeAsyncScript()` which will implement `callback` function and wait until expected value return as below :-

```
//this is the time out for executing async javascript
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement imageURL = driver.findElement(By.xpath(imageXpath));   
assertTrue((Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript("callback = arguments[1];callback(arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0)", imageURL));
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: @Taly could you share exact stacktrace??

Comment: @Taly omit `.getAttribute("src")` and try...see updated answer..:)

Comment: I omitted .getAttribute("src") as you suggested plus saved it as WebElement (instead of String) and  that solved it - thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception is because `executeScript` returns `null` and your code is expecting a `Boolean`.

It returns null because your script is accessing some HTMLElement properties (complete, naturalWidth) on a `String` which is the second argument provided to `executeScript`.

To make it work:

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath(imageXpath));

assertTrue((Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
  "return !!arguments[0].complete && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0;"
  , image))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! That was really helpful and indeed solved the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change from

```
String imageURL = driver.findElement(By.xpath(imageXpath)).getAttribute("src");
```

to

```
String imageURL = driver.findElement(By.xpath(imageXpath));
```

Rest of the code I hope correct or use the simple check -

```
Boolean imageLoaded1 = (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", imageURL);
  if (!imageLoaded1){
     System.out.println("Image is not present");
  }else{
     System.out.println("Got it");
  }
```